# is there some simple/clean way to make an "empty boolean variable" be evaluated as `false` on bash scripts?

Tags: bash

Well, the variable is not boolean until it has been set to `true` or `false`.

So when the script begins, it checks for a boolean that was not set yet as in `bTest=''`. So if I do this: `if $bTest;then echo "is active";fi` it will output "is active" when I would like it to show nothing...

I could use this: `[ "$bTest" == true ]`, when before was just `$bTest`, but to me that is the problem, it is not a "boolean", it is a string comparison...

Also, if I misstype a boolean variable name, it will be empty, and the script execution will throw no error message... and for several times I discovered the real problem was just the misstyped variable... Could an IDE have get that? I use `gedit` so I must track my failures by myself.

I wonder if is there a clean and simple way to work with booleans instead of typing `[ "$bTest" == true ]` every time..?

Comment: I believe true here is the literal string "true", not a boolean value of true. So you can consider "" as false and any other value as true. To check, you can use the `-z "$var"` test operator (to check for a zero-length string).

Comment: try this on terminal `true;echo $?;false;echo $?`, I think it is not just a string :). Also, my code would become this `[ ! -z "$bTest" ] && $bTest` and I would still be considering it as a string :(

Comment: `true` and `false` are shell builtins. `true` returns a status of 0, while `false` returns a status of 1. When doing `[ "$bTest" == true ]` you are not executing `true`, but rather comparing the string `true` to the string content of `$bTest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer, it sounds like you're actually trying to avoid typos.

The best way to do this, is to put

```
set -u
```

at the top of your shell script.

Then, instead of a typo expanding to an empty string, it is a fatal error.

```
if $bTest; then
    echo "is active"
fi

# => is active
```

Versus

```
set -u
if $bTest; then
    echo "is active"
fi

# => typo.sh: line 4: bTest: unbound variable
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to assign defaults to variables, it's usually best to do all the assignments at the top of the script like this:

```
: ${bTest:=false}
```

Finally, if you really want to type out a default value every time, you could use

```
if ${bTest:-false}; then
    echo "is active"
fi
```

Comment: cool, this works great for unset variables! as I make it sure to initialize them all, this may work indeed thx!

Comment: I am having trouble with empty parameters like `$1` or `${1:0:1}`, any tips?

Comment: How about `${1:-false}`?

Comment: it is my options loop: `while [[ "${1:0:2}" == "--" ]];do` I am trying to find a workaround..

Comment: For `$1`, it's more common to handle that explicitly at the start, e.g. `if test $# -eq 0; then echo "Usage..."; exit 2; fi`.  Or use `getopts`.

Comment: @samiam I needed to change my options loop to: `while ! ${1+false} && [[ "${1:0:2}" == "--" ]];do` as `${1-false}` will result that problem you mentioned in case $1 is `ls -l`, thx!

Comment: @Mikel long ago I gaveup on `getopts`, I will read about it again see if it may help, thx!

Comment: any workaround for count of unset array `${#arrayTest[@]}`? these didnt work `${#arrayTest[@]-}` `test ${#arrayTest[@]} -eq 0`; I think on wrap function with `set +u`; I am updating my full project and that is another exception :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is this:

```
if ${bTest:?};then echo "is active";fi
```

So I simply go from `$bTest` to `${bTest:?}` and no need to deal with anything more complex like functions and aliases.

Be concerned that as @samiam pointed out, it may cause a problem to you if the variable was actually set to something and that was a command like in `bTest='ls -l';if ${bTest:?};then echo "is active";fi` (where `ls -l` will be executed).

But in my case, I treat all "booleans" as booleans, so I only put `true` or `false` on them; the biggest problem I have been having with them for years is misstyped variable names; so I always got an empty "boolean" troubling me until I found that I misstyped it..

So, if you use your "booleans" with other values than `true` or `false`, do not use it; as it may become unsafe.

Comment: -1: Inaccurate (I just tested it in Bash).  That code expands the value of bTest in to a command run by Bash, and generates an error when bTest is not set.  `bTest='ls -l';if ${bTest:?};then echo "is active";fi` will run `ls -l`.  I'll undo my downvote as soon as the answer is corrected.

Comment: thx, I understand your concern about safety, but in my case I only use `true` or `false` with booleans. And before `${bTest:?}` I was already using `$bTest` and would already execute anything there! I still believe there may have some safer and still clean way to deal with it, I just couldnt figure out yet..

Comment: Is `if [-z "$bTest" ]; then echo "is active"; fi` clean enough for you?  If you *really* want it to look more boolean-like, there is `FALSE="";if[ "bTest" != "$FALSE" ]` etc.

Comment: if I set `bTest=true` it wont work with solely `[ -z "$bTest" ]`. I want to test the boolean in a way that _if it is empty, it be evaluated as false or throw error message_. `${bTest:?}` worked perfectly, but has the flaw you said, but not in my case as I only use `true` or `false` for booleans!

Comment: I have updated my answer to use functions called `is_true` and `is_false`.  I don't like throwing errors in Bash scripts because it halts execution when a script is called with `#!/bin/bash -e` (-e: Halt on any error)

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not have a boolean datatype (`/bin/true` and `/bin/false` are commands which return 1 and 0, because Bash, unintuitively interprets a return code of 0 as 'all is good' and anything else as 'there was a problem')

Indeed, Bash [does not have a numeric datatype](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html) (`A=$(( $A + 1 ))` converts `$A` in to an integer, adds one to it, then makes it a string again) and, more to the point, `0` does not have the same value as the empty string.  BASH is not PHP (where `var_dump(0 == "");` returns true).

Probably the best way to simulate booleans is as per aularon's suggestion: Use the -z operator, and consider empty strings false.  e.g `[ ! -z "$bTest" ] && $bTest`

If that's not clean enough for you, how about having `is_true` and `is_false` functions?

```
#!/bin/bash

is_true() {
        if [ "$1" = "false" ]; then
                return 1 # false
        fi
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                return 1 # false
        else
                return 0 # true
        fi
}

is_false() {
        if [ "$1" = "false" ]; then
                return 0 # true
        fi
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                return 0 # true
        else
                return 1 # false
        fi
}

A="1"
B=""

if is_true "$A" ; then
        echo A is true
else
        echo A is false
fi

if is_false "$A" ; then
        echo A is false
else
        echo A is true
fi

if is_true "$B" ; then
        echo B is true
else
        echo B is false
fi
```

Comment: in other words, you mean everything in bash are strings right? I understand the arguments, but I am still concerned about the simplicity and clean coding, try this `${bTest:?}` and the result will be what I was looking for!

Comment: Exactly!  Bash is a bit of a hack if you want super-clean code.  It is not Python. As another example, one has to explicitly variables to be local in functions.

Comment: my booleans are intended solely to `true` or `false`, this failed: `bTest=false;if is_true $bTest;then echo "is active";fi`

Comment: Having the string "false" evaluate to `false` is not how I would do it, but I have added code to make the is_true() and is_false() functions work that way.

Comment: the `is_true` is still failing for this `bTest=false;if is_true $bTest;then echo "is active";fi` :(

Comment: My bad.  Script updated to use `return`

Comment: `bTest=false;if is_true "$bTest" ;then echo "is active";fi` failed too, but there is another answer! `set -u` _any attempt on expanding unset variables will be fatal error_; worked perfectly, check it out! I think fatal errors are important to keep the code strong, may be C++ influence :).

Comment: Another way to make sure errors stop execution is to run Bash scripts with `#!/bin/bash -e`, which makes commands not followed by `||` that fail terminate the script.  (As an aside, I have fixed the script, but I don't think that's what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Shells convert environment variables to shell variables. So you should never use a variable uninitialised as one day or another your script will break because for a reason or another a variable by the same name was in the environment that shell received on startup.

So:

```
#! /bin/sh -
bTest=false

while getopts ...;
  ... ) bTest=true
done

if "$bTest"; then
```

(don't forget the quotes, leaving out the quotes is the split+glob operator. Note that if `$bTest` is empty, you'll get an error about the empty string being not found as a command).

Now, if you want to ignore the advice. Another way using ksh syntax (works also in `bash` and `zsh`) is to use arithmetic expressions and `1` or any non-zero value to mean true.

0 and the empty string mean false in arithmetic expressions.

So you can do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
while getopts ...;
  ... ) bTest=1
done
if ((bTest)); then...
```

But beware that your script may stop working if for some reason there's a `bTest` in the environment (for instance because your script is called from another script that uses the same variable name and exported it (for instance because of a `set -a` or because it's a `rc` script where all variables are in the environment)).